# cropping some part of a png image with tikz

Tags: tikz-pgf, graphics

A follow up to this [answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/422454):

I am clipping a png image to which I want to specify scaled coordinates for the `crop` command.

So that

```
\clip (0,0) rectangle + (1,1);
```

crops nothing, and

```
\clip (0,0) rectangle + (0.4,0.6);
```

crops 40% in the x direction and 60% in the y direction.

How can I do it?

MWE

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
Lorem ipsum

\begin{tikzpicture}
\clip (0,0) rectangle + (1,1);
{\includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{image01.png}};
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

where `image01.png` is [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dUw9S.png)

Comment: Related: https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/9559/86

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First you need to measure the width and height of the image using a savebox (or at least the height if you specify with width).

The only way I know of to use `\includegraphics` (or `\usebox`) is inside a node.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
Lorem ipsum

\begin{tikzpicture}
\sbox0{\includegraphics{example-image}}% get width and height

\begin{scope}[xscale={\wd0/1cm}, yscale={\ht0/1cm}, local bounding box=A]
\clip (0,0) rectangle (1,1);
\node[above right, inner sep=0pt] at (0,0) {\usebox0};
\end{scope}

\begin{scope}[xscale={\wd0/1cm}, yscale={\ht0/1cm}, shift=(A.north west)]
\clip (0,0) rectangle (0.4,0.6);
\node[above right, inner sep=0pt] at (0,0) {\usebox0};
\end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```